# Jquery 3.2.1 error: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined

Tags: jquery

The fade in on the following gives a console error: `Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined` It fades out fine, then fades in fine, but wont fade out again. Should I be using a different function?

```
<div id="MenuButtonDiv" > 
    <img id="MenuButton" src="images/MenuButton.png" > 
</div>

 <script>

    HideMenuButton();

    function HideMenuButton()
    {
        $( "#MenuButton" ).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut(1000);
    }

    function ShowMenuButton()
    {
        $( "#MenuButton" ).fadeIn();
    }

    $("#MenuButtonDiv").hover(function(){
        ShowMenuButton();
      }, function(){
        HideMenuButton();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/n692y91g/

Comment: The error should have a file and line number beside (which will possibly be clickable). I suspect it points to some entirely different piece of code.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with no console errors. Do you have any browser extensions that might get in the way? Perhaps you could update JQuery?

Comment: @BrandonFlynn-NB Turns out it was a bit of automatically generated coldfusion code.